# Suggest message beeps, blips and boops for the third place (the chat)

Tags: discussion, chat

What beeps, blips or boops should be used when for the third place?

I am talking about the sound played when a message is received on chat.meta.stackoverflow.com and pals.

**Edit** by balpha: We'd really like to get more suggestions on this. So go ahead and find nice sounds! Please be sure to include any neccessary information (e.g. license). When each Stack Exchange site has its own chat, they should of course also have their own distinguishable sounds.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about, but it is spelled "boobs".

Comment: @ladybug shh, if I use the correct spelling the close police will be on me in _no_ time!

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about either. Does it have something to do with [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXKOsajNZY4)?

Comment: Obviously, @gnovince. Edited question.

Answer (score 7):

I think we should have different sounds for general messages and mentions. Also, there should be a difference based on when a room is "active" in any one tab and when it's just "idle", sitting in the background with messages scrolling on the sidebar

I'm using [Tonematrix](http://lab.andre-michelle.com/tonematrix) to quickly build the sounds in some kind of minimalist fashion. Rightclick-paste the data in the codeblock to play the associated sound.

In order of "severity":

1. Message on idle room:

   ```
   65536,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
   ```
2. Message on active room:

   ```
   65536,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
   ```
3. Mention on active room:

   ```
   65536,8,16,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
   ```
4. Mention on idle room:

   ```
   65536,8,24,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
   ```

---

Woo! I managed to make a screenshot!

[image: Screenshot!]

Comment: Can you do a right-click copy and paste of the sounds?

Comment: Didn't know you could do that! Sure. @waiwai933 done!

Comment: OK, tonematrix is great fun.

Answer (score 4):

I've wasted most of the day listening to countless sound clips, searching for a good set of distinctive-yet-unobtrusive aural indicators... And at long last, I think I have the perfect mix:

1. Message on idle room: 
   [Wilhelm scream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:WilhelmScream.ogg)
2. Message on active room:
   [Wilhelm scream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:WilhelmScream.ogg)
3. Mention on active room:
   [Wilhelm scream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:WilhelmScream.ogg)
4. Mention on idle room: 
   [Crickets ch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Field_cricket_Gryllus_pennsylvanicus.ogg)- no, scratch that, use [Wilhelm scream](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:WilhelmScream.ogg)

Answer (score 2):

Please allow us to turn them off.

Comment: That's possible, and has been from the beginning. Click the speaker icon (top right). I guess we should add that to the FAQ.

Comment: I am _so_ glad you posted this "answer".  I would never have spotted that the speaker icon had a mute button.  Now that I get triple beeps, it is delightful to be able to switch them off.

Answer (score 0):

I've always been a big fan of the Mac Classic [Wild Eep](http://mac.wikia.com/wiki/Wild_Eep). It may be copyrighted, but it may have already been stolen. The statute of limitations has run out* and there's no honor among thieves.

<sup><sub>* According to my lolyer, O. Mann Dewie of Dewie, Cheatham and Howe.</sub></sup>

Answer (score -1):

Some of the soundjay sounds are quite good IMO:

http://www.soundjay.com/button-sounds-1.html

Browse around the first few pages.