# Default sounds in chat should be "only when mentioned"

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, audio

The default sound setting in the chat web interface is pretty intrusive, with a bleep for every time anybody says anything. Suggest that the default sound be changed to "only when mentioned" to cut down on the bleeping.

Comment: Agreed; the sound is cool, but far too frequent.

Comment: Agreed. If you're watching an important, quiet room you can always change to "Visible Room".

Comment: [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58350/suggest-message-beeps-blips-and-boops-for-the-third-place-the-chat)

Comment: Oh, is _that_ what was really happening [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61142/about-your-fing-website)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed; we'll roll this change out over the next couple of days.

The reason that we don't just flip the switch is that we want it to be as unsurprising as possible to the user; so a user who *wants* "visible room" as their setting and relies on this default value will not be silently degraded to "when mentioned".

Answer (score 4):

I agree. Defaulting to sound on every messages is distracting and detracts from the usefulness of an alerting sound marking something as an important event. I usually don't find every message in a chat room to be of the utmost importance qualifying it for a sound, especially not if I'm actively following the conversation.